# Configurar sonido de notificación personalizado en aplicación Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Quiero configurar un sonido personalizado que suene cada vez que llegue una notificación, llamada o SMS al dispositivo, siempre según el usuario lo requiera. Algo como esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El hecho es que estoy intentando hacerlo de la siguiente manera pero el programa me arroja dos errores:

**Errores:**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Multiple items at content://media/internal/audio/media

java.lang.SecurityException: Uri is not ringtone, alarm, or notification: content://media/internal/audio/media
```

**Programa:**

```
ringtone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(listener!= null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            //Aca iria para poner el audio como ringtone.

                            Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath("android.resource://"+ context.getPackageName() +"/raw/test");

                            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context,
                                    RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, uri);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Me gustaría saber como puedo solucionar esos problemas y/o hacer funcionar mi idea, ya que estuve navegando por bastantes preguntas similares en el foro en Ingles y aun no encuentro ninguna solución.

Comment: Hola, primero asegura declarar y aceptar el permiso WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE y posteriormente obtener la URI del archivo ubicado en el directorio /raw, agrego la forma correcta en la respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

El primer error es causado cuando no se encuentra la ruta del archivo:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Multiple
>   items at content://media/internal/audio/media

El segundo error se debe a que tu aplicación no tiene definido el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Uri is not ringtone, alarm, or
>   notification: content://media/internal/audio/media

Primeramente asegura definir el permiso en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

y requerirlo manualmente, para esto puedes llamar este método:

```
public boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Permission is granted");
            return true;
        } else {

            Log.v(TAG, "Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 255);
            return false;
        }
    } else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        Log.v(TAG, "Permission is granted");
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

#### Obtener URI de archivo en /raw y definirlo como Ringtone

Ahora, si tratas de cargar un archivo de audio llamado `test` y este esta ubicado en el directorio `/raw`, debes obtener primeramente su URI de esta forma:

```
Uri soundUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://"+ getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.test);
```

una vez que obtuviste la URI, ahora puedes definirla para que defina el sonido actual

```
 RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context,
                                    RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, soundUri );
```

Comment: Hola Jorgesys! En breves tendré tiempo y probare la respuesta, en cuanto funcione, en el caso de que lo hago te entrego la recompensa! Muchas gracias de antemano!