# El sonido de notificación personalizado no funciona en Android Oreo

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

buenas noches, estoy presentado problemas con referencia a las notificaciones en dispositivos, Había copiado el archivo mp3 (bell.mp3) en la carpeta raw en la carpeta res. Cuando se activa la notificación, produce un sonido mp3 dado hasta Android Nougat pero un sonido predeterminado en Android Oreo . Había referido muchos sitios, pero nada funcionó en Android Oreo . No encontré ningún cambio en Android Docs con respecto al sonido de notificación en Android O y superior. ¿Qué cambios se deben hacer para que este código funcione también en Android O?, la notificación se muestra pero no suena, estuve leyendo en varios foros donde comentan que hay que habilitar permisos de sonido y notificaciones desde configuraciones, pero sigo sin tener éxito.

En el servicio se ejecuta un método de donde tomo la respuesta que se va a mostrar en la notificación.

```
  Context contexto = getApplicationContext();
    UtileriaNotificaciones utileriaNotificaciones = new UtileriaNotificaciones(contexto);
    msg = getString(R.string.nuevo_siniestro, msg);
    Intent intent = new Intent(contexto, Siniestro2.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    utileriaNotificaciones.crearNotificacionReporte(getString(R.string.app_name), msg, R.drawable.notifica2, intent);
```

En mi clase UtileriaNotificaciones creo la notificación y paso la respuesta a mostrar.

```
private Context contexto;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

public UtileriaNotificaciones(Context contexto) {

    this.contexto = contexto;
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)contexto.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

}

public void crearNotificacionReporte(String titulo, String texto, int icono, Intent intent){

    // El identificador del canal
    //String id = "canal_general";
    Notification notification;
    // Configure the notification channel.

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(contexto, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    // Sets an ID for the notification, so it can be updated.
    int notifyID = 2;
    // The id of the channel.
    String CHANNEL_ID = "canal_general";
    // Create a notification and set the notification channel.

    Uri sound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + contexto.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.bell);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "HDI", importance);

        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .build();

        mChannel.setDescription("NA");
        mChannel.enableLights(true);
        mChannel.setLightColor(Color.YELLOW);
        mChannel.enableVibration(true);
        mChannel.setSound(sound, audioAttributes);
        mChannel.setVibrationPattern(VIBRACION);

        if (mNotificationManager != null) {

            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);

        }

        notification = new Notification.Builder(contexto, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notifica2)
                .setContentTitle(titulo)
                .setContentText(texto)
                .setSmallIcon(icono)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(false)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
        // Issue the notification.
        mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, notification);

    } else {
        final String ANDROID_RESOURCE_S_D = "android.resource://%s/%d";

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(contexto)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notifica2)
            .setContentTitle(contexto.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(texto)
            .setSound(Uri.parse(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), ANDROID_RESOURCE_S_D, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, R.raw.bell)))//.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + contexto.getPackageName() + R.raw.bell))
            .setVibrate(UtileriaNotificaciones.VIBRACION)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(false)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        Notification notificacion = mBuilder.build();
        mBuilder.build().flags |= Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
        mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, notificacion);

    }

}
```

Espero que puedan apoyarme, sería de gran ayuda sus retroalimentación .

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente debes asegurar tener definido en tu AndroidManifest.xml así como realizar la petición manual del permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Es importante que asegures tener tu archivo `bell.mp3` dentro del directorio `/raw`:

```
Uri sound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + contexto.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.bell);
```

esta uri se define en el método `setSound()` de `NotificationCompat.Builder` :

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(contexto)
            ...
            ...
            .setSound(sound)
            ...
```

Revisa:

[Configurar sonido de notificación personalizado en aplicación Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/333653/configurar-sonido-de-notificaci%C3%B3n-personalizado-en-aplicaci%C3%B3n-android)